# Проблемы с primary key в связке Hibernate / PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, spring, hibernate

В какой-то незамеченный момент перестало работать добавление сущностей: Hibernate пытается добавить запись с null в качестве id, PostgreSQL расценивает это как нарушение констрейнта и отказывается добавить запись, приложение вылетает с соответствующим исключением. Подобная проблема проявляется на аналогичных сущностях в постгре 9.3 и 9.4:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "supertable")
class Entity {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) // AUTO и SEQUENCE тоже пробовал с аналогичным результатом
@Column
private Long id;

...
}
```

Что я мог поломать? И где искать полноценную доку по GeneratedType, которая более-менее полно объяснит, чем именно я вообще управляю?

Comment: в самом постгресе тип поля какой: bigserial или bigint?

Comment: @zzashpaupat это на самом деле один тип bigint. Sequence для поля существует. Создавался через liquibase (т.е. оригинального DDL-запроса я не знаю), и, возможно, в два этапа, но это никак влиять не должно.

Comment: я понимаю, что это один тип на самом деле. может, в Hibernate где-то interceptor встраивается и айдишник обнуляет? или AOP какое-нибудь?

Comment: @zzashpaupat там другая ситуация, он его не обнуляет, он неправильно создает запись, включая в INSERT-запрос null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ, конечно, валялся рядом. В dev-окружении у меня перебивались настройки по умолчанию (H2 заменялся на постгрес), но я банально забыл указать в конфигурации новый dialectClassName для Hibernate, поэтому он вел себя с постгресом, как с H2.